# Dynamic sort with Redis

Tags: python, redis

Let's say I have 5 entries in my Redis database:

- `news::id`: the ID of the last news;
- `news::list`: a list of all news IDs;
- `news:n` where *n* is the news ID: a hash containing fields such as `title`, `url`, etc.;
- `news:n:upvotes`: a list of all users' IDs who upvoted the news, thus giving the number of upvotes.
- `news:n:downvotes`: a list of all users' IDs who downvoted the news, thus giving the number of downvotes.

Then I have multiple ranking algorithms, where `rank =`:

1. `upvotes_count`;
2. `upvotes_count - downvotes_count`;
3. `upvotes_count - downvotes_count - age`;
4. `upvotes_count / downvotes_count`;
5. `age`.

Now how do I sort those news according to each of these algorithms?

I thought about computing the different ranks on every votes, but then if I introduce a new algorithm I need to compute the new rank for all the news.

[`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) could help but it won't be available until v2.6, which surely I don't want to wait for.

Eventually, I could retrieve all the news and put them in a Python list. But again it translates into a high memory usage, not to mention the fact that Redis stores its data in memory.

So is there a proper way to do this or should I just move to MongoDB?

Comment: Can you give different (reasonable) weights to different parameters, such as `100000000 * upvotes_count - 10000 * downvotes_count - age` and sort just once according to this weighted sum?

Comment: @eumiro Nope, **the goal here is to be able to sort with different algos**. Also, see my edits.

Comment: Sorry to hijack those comments, but you did delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626415/git-log-with-dulwich (git-log with Dulwich). Did you find an answer?

Comment: @VonC Nope, I ended up using GitPython instead

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by constants stored in keys.

In your example, I can sort `1.` almost trivially using Redis. If you store the other expression values after calculating them, you can sort by them too. For `1.`, you will need to store the list count somewhere, I will assume `news:n:upvotes:count`.

The catch is to use the [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command. For instance, the first sort would be:

```
SORT news::list BY news:*:upvotes:count GET news:*->title GET news:*->url
```

...to get titles and urls sorted by upvotes, in crescent order.

There are modifiers too, for `alpha` sorting, and `asc/desc` sorting. Read the command page entirely, it is worthwhile.

PS: You can wrap the count, store, sort and possibly deletion of count in a [MULTI](http://redis.io/commands/multi)/[EXEC](http://redis.io/commands/exec) environment (a transaction).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've actually figured out how to sort `1.` but I don't seem to be able to do so for `2-4.`. Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome. As I said, if you store the calculations on new keys, you can use the sort command as above (specifying the new key in the `BY` clause, replacing `n` with `*`). Star operator will be replaced by each and every id that is in the key that follows `SORT` command. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh I see, but I'd like not to store the ranks.

Comment: Why so ? You can do that in a transaction, the required execution time will be very small, and it probably won't add much to total memory used. With the positive fact that you won't have to rely on code in sorting itself. I see that, or then doing _sort_ in code.

Comment: Yes but if I sort with Python I need to load all the news in memory again.

Comment: "Don't fall into the specification spiral—at some point you need to start coding". Make a decision and go for it.