# Redis sorting syntax in python for a queue of lists or dictionaries

Tags: python, web-services, sorting, dictionary, redis

I'm trying to sort a Redis queue for a website I'm helping a good friend with, but I'm unclear on the syntax for sorting within python. The website already used Redis heavily in the backend when I got it, so I've been trying to figure out how to work with Redis and the existing architecture. I have the following queue that I want to sort based on a particular field:

```
personal_queue = RedisQueue(name=personal_queuename, host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

where personal_queuename is a string

The queue contains this information in each entry (slightly simplified) in the current implementation of the website:

```
':'.join((str(partner_id), str(relative_rating)))
```

So it's sort of like a queue of dictionaries, except there aren't really any keys unless you think of the index in the queue as a key that maps to basically a list of strings. I want to sort this queue by the relative_rating string (which should be converted to an integer) so that the entry with the smallest value of relative_rating is at the top/front of the queue. My question is if this is possible, how to do it, and/or how to reorganize the queue to sort by this if it's not possible with the current implementation. I'm going to be sorting other slightly different queues too, so knowing how to sort in this way will allow me to sort other things with the same basic structure.

I've seen people mentioning how to sort using general Redis syntax, but I can't find anything specifying how to sort 1) specifically using **python** code or 2) on the specific fields I want to work with since they're kind of hard to get at (not my idea to organize it this way, but it makes sense and maybe Redis just needs data to be organized this way?). I think I might have to modify the data in some way, but since I'm unfamiliar with Redis and need to change the backend of the site a little I am not sure what values to pass to the sort function even with a simpler problem.

I figured out that the syntax is basically:

```
sort(personal_queuename, by=None, get=None)
```

but I have no idea what to put in place of None. I'm very new to this so if you could explain both the type of information that goes in each field and what that corresponds to in my case that would help me a lot. I can change the data around a little but I need to be able to map the partner_ids to the relative_ratings (for instance, the way I'm doing it now) and preferably map the partner_ids to mulitple fields like this:

```
':'.join((str(partner_id), other_field1, other_field2, str(relative_rating)))
```

And I need to do this using the Redis queue because of the other backend implementation (it previously did not sort the queues but still extensively makes use of their data).

RedisQueue is this class:

```
import redis

class RedisQueue(object):

    def __init__(self, name, **redis_kwargs):
        '''Initializes connection to specified redis queue.
           The default connection parameters are: host='localhost', port=6379, db=0'''
        self.__db = redis.Redis(**redis_kwargs)
        self.key = name

    def qsize(self):
        """Return the size of the queue."""
        return self.__db.llen(self.key)

    def empty(self):
        """Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise."""
        return self.qsize() == 0

    def push(self, item):
        """Place an item into the queue."""
        self.__db.rpush(self.key, item)

    def pop(self, block=False, timeout=None):
        """Remove and return an item from the queue.
        If optional argument block is true and timeout is None (the default), block
        if necessary until an item becomes available."""
        if block:
            item = self.__db.blpop(self.key, timeout=timeout)
            if item:
                item = item[1]
        else:
            item = self.__db.lpop(self.key)
        return item

    def rem(self, item):
        self.__db.lrem(self.key, item, 1)

    def all(self):
        return self.__db.lrange(self.key, 0, -1)

    def get_nowait(self):
        """Equivalent to get(False)."""
        return self.get(False)
```

I've already looked at these links but couldn't figure out how to acccess the data field I want to sort by (using python syntax, which is key to me - I'm aware that there are answers referencing general Redis syntax):

https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

[Indexing using Redis sorted sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431719/indexing-using-redis-sorted-sets)

[How to remove items in a sorted set using python in redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181773/how-to-remove-items-in-a-sorted-set-using-python-in-redis)

[Dynamic sort with Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589737/dynamic-sort-with-redis)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you look at https://github.com/nvie/rq?

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with what I'm working with...that looks like a separate module, and I couldn't find anything about sorting in the repository. I also said I can't just replace the existing architecture...I just want to know how to use Redis python's sorting capability...

Comment: I'm not aware of Redis queues (or LISTs in redis's term) have any sorting feature http://redis.io/commands#list

Comment: This isn't a regular redis list (and a queue is not a list), hence why its own class exists (see the constructor I included), and redis lists do have a sorting function. http://redis.io/commands#
See sort, which sorts a list, set, or sorted set. The function is definitely real, I'm just asking about the syntax...